# How do I go about checking the existence of records in all tables JOIN`ed in a statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want ensure none of the tables included through `INNER JOIN` return 0 rows, resulting in an empty result-set due to the join being `INNER`. I want to be able to return information to the user about which table had no records, causing the query to return empty.

PS: Please ignore Foreign Keys for this question.

**Example-query**:

```
SELECT * FROM Person P
INNER JOIN [User] U ON U.PersonId = P.Id
INNER JOIN Email E ON E.UserId = U.Id
INNER JOIN Company C on C.Id = U.CompanyId
WHERE P.Id = 3
```

Let's say the user had no associated `Email`-records. I then want to be able to tell the user about this. Note: I only need to print the first failing step, I.E if the user has no `Email` and no `Company`, I only need to tell the user about him not having any `Email`.

**How I would have solved it earlier**:
I would perform the complete query in steps, building it up join by join, doing a whole lot of redundant querying. I really don't like this solution at all, which is why I'm asking for help.

```
-- Ensure Person exists 
IF NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM Person P
    WHERE P.Id = 3 
) 
BEGIN
    PRINT 'No associated Person was found';
    RETURN 1;
END

-- Ensure User exists 
IF NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM Person P
    INNER JOIN [User] U ON U.PersonId = P.Id
    WHERE P.Id = 3 
) 
BEGIN
    PRINT 'No associated User was found';
    RETURN 1;
END
```

And so on. How can I write this more concise, in a way that solves the same problem but avoids repeating queries?

Thanks in advance.

**Update**
By looking at the answers, I realized my example was bad. Using `LEFT JOIN` is ok in this example, since the "join-chain" is not straight; Person joins User, then User joins in multiple directions, like this:

```
Person - User - Email
          |
        Company
```

I'll try to provide a different example:

```
SELECT * FROM a
INNER JOIN b ON b.a_id = a.id
INNER JOIN c ON c.b_id = b.id
INNER JOIN d ON d.c_id = c.id
INNER JOIN e ON e.d_id = d.id
INNER JOIN f ON f.e_id = e.id
INNER JOIN g ON g.f_id = f.id
```

The join-chain would then look like this:

```
a - b - c - d - e - f - g
```

If I were to use `LEFT JOIN`'s to ensure existence of records, the IIF/CASE statements would get pretty terrible. Example:

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN b.id is null THEN 'b is null' END as b_is_null
CASE WHEN b.id is not null and c.id is null THEN 'b is null' END as c_is_null
..
CASE WHEN b.id is not null and c.id is not null and d.id is not null and e.id is not null and f.id is not null and g.id is null THEN 'g is null' AS g_is_null
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b ON b.a_id = a.id
LEFT JOIN c ON c.b_id = b.id
LEFT JOIN d ON d.c_id = c.id
LEFT JOIN e ON e.d_id = d.id
LEFT JOIN f ON f.e_id = e.id
LEFT JOIN g ON g.f_id = f.id
```

It can get really ugly. And these examples are with 1-character alias-names and 2-character property-names.
Keep in mind, I also want to check if the first table (`Person`/`a`, the one not joined) also returns rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use left join. From your query, if a person doesn't have any user they obviously doesn't have any email or company. So all left join will be fine.

```
SELECT P.*, 
IIF(U.PersonID IS NULL, 0, 1) AS isUserExists,
IIF(E.UserId IS NULL, 0, 1) AS isEmailExists, 
IIF(C.Id IS NULL, 0, 1) AS isCompanyInformationExists
FROM Person P
LEFT JOIN [User] U ON U.PersonId = P.Id
LEFT JOIN Email E ON E.UserId = U.Id
LEFT JOIN Company C on C.Id = U.CompanyId
WHERE P.Id = 3
```

If `U.PersonID IS NULL` then no user existed, if `E.UserId IS NULL` then no email existed, if `C.Id IS NULL` then no company information existed for that person. By this you can use your messages as you need.

Answer (score 0):

Use case statements like below and print your message.

```
 select 
    case when u.PersonId is null and p.id is not null then 'user not exists'
         WHEN u.PersonId IS NOT NULL AND p.id IS NOT NULL AND e.mailid is null THEN 'mail id not exist'
    else 'No associated Person was found' end message
     FROM Person P
    left JOIN [User] U ON U.PersonId = P.Id
    left JOIN Email E ON E.UserId = U.Id
    left  JOIN Company C on C.Id = U.CompanyId
    WHERE P.Id = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Email VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @Company VARCHAR(50)

SELECT @Email = E.Email, @Company = C.CompanyName FROM Person P
INNER JOIN [User] U ON U.PersonId = P.Id
LEFT JOIN Email E ON E.UserId = U.Id
LEFT JOIN Company C on C.Id = U.CompanyId
WHERE P.Id = 3

IF @Email IS NULL
Print 'NO Email'

IF @Company IS NULL
Print 'No Company'
```

Comment: If the variable-checks are performed in the order from which they're joined, this can work! It feels cleaner than left joins as well. I'll leave the question open for a little, as I'd be really interested in a solution without variables as well.

Comment: that isn't really right though, an ID could have an Email, but no company - but you are then  going to tell him that he has no Email an no company - because no records can be returned if any table is missing

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, I updated my answer, Instead of left join I written inner join